# What is the best way to clean an electric fryer?

Tags: equipment, cleaning, oil, fryer

I have a Rival RCF15 fryer. I lost the manual and can't find a copy online. It has a fixed metal reservoir for the oil. It has a removable basket. I remember the manual saying something about not exposing the heating element to water, so I've been cautious about cleaning it.

Fast forward a few years, the fryer is coated with a layer or brown oil...mostly on the inside, and some on the outside(which is made of plastic).  What would you guys recommend for cleaning this?

Should I just throw this away and get a better model that's easier to clean?

Comment: Is the heating element removable and is the entire inside surface metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restaurant supply stores carry degreaser, which will remove the brown baked on oil.  However, that oil isn't hurting your cooking at all.  It is the same thing that forms on cast iron skillets, but it isn't objectionable because you don't notice the color against the black of the cast iron.  If it works I'd continue to use it.

If you are thinking of changing, you might want to consider the cast iron Dutch Oven route.  They hold their heat better than consumer deep fryers and a Dutch oven can do more than just deep fry.  And they are easier to clean.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with fryer, but I have a simple way of cleaning most of the kitchenwares.

For inside:

I would try to put in a mixture of water and dish washing powder. Leave the mixture inside the fryer for about 1 - 2 hours and you should see the grease start to come out. Then pour the water out and use a brush with clean water to try cleaning out the greasy bits.

For outside:

A small amount of detergent with warm water should clean outside should do the job.